# How to connect to server using MySql.Data?

Tags: c#, mysql, wpf, webserver, connection-string

I am making an C# WPF application to connect to a webserver database. However it gives me "Unable to connect to any of the specified MySql hosts" exception. It works with a local host but not with an actual server. For now I am just trying to test the connection but it does not work.

```
string connectionString = "Server=195.201.171.163;UserID=******;Password=*****;";

        private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                try
                {
                    conn.Open();  // Gives exception here
                    MessageBox.Show("Success");
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                }

            }
        }
```

Comment: You didn't specify the port (maybe: 3306) and database in your connection string... It also could be a privilege issue...

Comment: Ok I just tried the port thing. My port number was 80. But now it gives me "Reading from the stream has failed" exception.